# Run Jenkins Job In Python Using Token

Tags: python, jenkins, request

I want to run Jenkins job with the use of tokens.
But this piece of code gives  *403* error.

How to avoid this problem? I will not use username and password, Only token.
Is there any way to do this?

**Code:**

```
import requests
try:
    build = requests.get("http://jenkins_url/jenkins_job_name/build?token=TokenFromJob")
except Exception as e:
    print ("Failed triggering the Jenkins job")
print (build.status_code)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/authenticating-scripted-clients/). Jenkins doesnt do authorization. So even after you have generated authorization key you need to handle authorization in your python script.

> Note that Jenkins does not do any authorization negotiation. i.e. it
> immediately returns a 403 (Forbidden) response instead of a 401
> (Unauthorized) response, so make sure to send the authentication
> information from the first request (aka "preemptive authentication").

Here is what i have in my setup. Need To pass username and api token as below. You do not need to pass token to the build url once you are logged in.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

session = requests.Session()
login_response = session.post(JENKINS_URL,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME,API_TOKEN))
# check is status code is successfull
# then do other things
build = requests.get("http://jenkins_url/jenkins_job_name/build")
print (build.status_code)
```